# Value semantics in c# struct vs tuple

Tags: c#

So I'm making my first steps in C# and was making a simple tile puzzle. When I was modeling the position of a tile I wanted to have value semantics. So, as far as I can see there are basically two ways of doing this, with a struct or with a Tuple.

In the case of the Tuple my code looks like this:

> ```
> public class TilePosition : Tuple<int,int>
> {
>     public int HComponent{get { return Item1; }}
>     public int VComponent{get { return Item2; }}
>
>    public TilePosition(int horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition)
>         : base(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

The struct solution would look like this:

> ```
> public struct TilePosition 
>  {
>     private readonly int hComponent;
>     private readonly int vComponent;
>     public int HComponent { get { return hComponent; } }
>     public int VComponent { get { return vComponent; } }
>
>    public TilePosition(int hComponent, int vComponent)
>     {
>         this.hComponent = hComponent;
>         this.vComponent = vComponent;
>     }
>
>    public static bool operator ==(TilePosition position1, TilePosition position2)
>     {
>         return position1.Equals(position2);
>     }
>
>    public static bool operator !=(TilePosition position1, TilePosition position2)
>     {
>         return !(position1 == position2);
>     }
> }
> ```

The tuple is conciser but it exposes `Item1` and `Item2` which would be confusing in a public API, even though I have added the H and V component properties around them.

The struct need more code and I get a compiler warning about how I should override Equals and GetHashCode because I'm overriding `==` and `!=`, but if I do that I'm not getting anything from using a struct (from the semantic and syntactic point of view) because it wold be exactly the same code with a conventional class.

So are there any benefits from using a struc over a subclassed Tuple aside from not having the noise of the Item properties?

Would both of my solution behave in the same way as I expect or are there nuances I should be aware of?

Comment: Why do you say deriving from `Tuple<,>` gives you "value semantics". The `Tuple<,>` class is a reference type, and your deriving class is a reference type too, of course.

Comment: Tuple<T1,T2> is a reference type, so doing comparing two tile positions using == will compare references, not the values of the X and Y coords. I think this is not what you want?

Comment: It could be what he wants, if two tiles are not allowed to occupy the same space. The positions being equal (also in reference) would mean they occupy the same space.

Comment: It is more that in both cases you get Equals and GetHashCode for free. But yes, I would also have to override the operators in Tuple. I got that wrong there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(As an aside, it would be good to implement `IEquatable<TilePosition>` in both cases too - particularly in the struct case, to avoid boxing.)

> So are there any benefits from using a struc over a subclassed Tuple aside from not having the noise of the Item properties?

Given that it's immutable, in both cases you have roughly "value semantics" in both cases, but there are still differences...

- An instance of the class type requires space on the heap (assuming no escape detection etc by the CLR); a value of the struct type *may* in some cases only use the stack
- Passing a value of the class type just means passing a reference (4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on CLR architecture); passing a value of the struct type really passes the values (so 8 bytes)
- In the class type version `null` is a valid value; in the struct type version you'd need to use `TilePosition?` to indicate a possibly-absent value
- In the struct version `new TilePosition()` is valid and will have values of 0 for both fields (and this will be the default value, e.g. for fields and array elements)
- As you haven't sealed your class, someone could create a mutable subclass; it's therefore *not* safe for clients to assume it's fully immutable. (You should probably seal it...)
- You can use your class type with any code which uses `Tuple<,>`, whereas that's clearly not the case for the struct type
- The meaning of `==` will differ between the two types. Even if you overload `==` in the class type, a caller could still end up just comparing references. And in the struct case, you could still end up comparing *boxed* references, unhelpfully.

These are just *differences* of course - whether they count as *benefits* for one approach or the other depends on your requirements.

Comment: By a mutable subclass, do you mean a class with extra fields that are mutable, or is there some way for a descendant to mutate the `xComponent` `int`s I can't see?

Comment: If you overload `==` in a class, the "built-in" overload of `==` for reference types, that is `operator ==(object, object)` might get called instead if overload resolution (which happens at binding-time) picks that overload. I think this is what you point out in the last bullet. But if you overload `==` in a struct, an analogous thing may happen: The `operator ==(object, object)` overload may be called with **boxed** values of the struct, and this compares references to the box (or boxes), which is not useful.

Comment: @Rawling: I mean adding a field along with a way of mutating it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a jagged array and holding an item on each field. This would more closely follow the tile puzzle:

- Tiles and space for them is a 1:1 mapping. So each tile/space can only have one space/tile.
- No need to compare tile components.
- Moving tiles is easy, example

  ```
      if (fields[x, y] = null)
      {
          fields[x, y] = fields[oldX, oldY];
          fields[oldX, oldY] = null;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do it properly and put in all the work. If you want a struct rather than a class (which may be appropriate for you), here's a sample implementation:

```
public struct TilePosition: IEquatable<TilePosition>
{
    public TilePosition(int horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition)
    {
        _x = horizontalPosition;
        _y = verticalPosition;
    }

    public int HComponent
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
    }

    public int VComponent
    {
        get
        {
            return _y;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator == (TilePosition lhs, TilePosition rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator != (TilePosition lhs, TilePosition rhs)
    {
        return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public bool Equals(TilePosition other)
    {
        return (_x == other._x) && (_y == other._y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is TilePosition && Equals((TilePosition)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (_x*397) ^ _y;
        }
    }

    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Although I don't think you really need the `if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) { return false; }` part.

Comment: True because if obj is null, the "is TilePosition" will return false. Note: This code was automatically generated by Resharper. :) I'll remove the extra test (and I might ask JetBrains why Resharper puts it in... ;)